# how to get div that by remove by remove method in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to get a div which was removed by remove method in jquery, I want to get the div on another method.

```
function viewregister()
{
   //code goes here

}

function removeregister()
{       $("#registerContent").remove();
}
```

Comment: you want to get content of div on another function ?

Comment: Maybe rather than remove it, you should `hide()` it, then its content will still be available.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `remove()`, use [`detach()`](https://api.jquery.com/detach/), which does the same work as `remove()` but keeps all the data intact and provide you with the reference of the removed element, so that you can re-insert it when needed.

```
var ref;

function viewregister() {
   // Insert the element again in the body
   $('body').append(ref);
}

function removeregister() {
  // Save the reference to the element in a variable
  ref = $("#registerContent").detach();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remember the element in a variable, and use that variable in `viewregister`:

```
var registerContent = null;
function viewregister()
{
    if (registerContent) {
        // Do something with it, such as appending it ot the DOM
        registerContent.appendTo("some element");
        registerContent = null;
    }
}

function removeregister()
{
    if (!registerContent) {
        registerContent = $("#registerContent").remove();
    }
}
```

You might use [`detach`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) instead of [`remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/). The only difference is that `remove` removes event handlers and data you've associated with the element via the [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method; `detach` leaves them alone.

Alternately, you may just want to hide and show:

```
function viewregister()
{
    $("#registerContent").show();
}

function removeregister()
{
    $("#registerContent").hide();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure [.remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) return the removed element. `.detach()`  return  it for sure

Comment: @AlonEitan - Yes, `remove` returns the removed element. Like most jQuery methods, it returns the jQuery set you call it on. In the docs you linked, it even says "Returns: jQuery" (although it would be nice if it said what that jQuery object contains :-) ).